# variable not working in p5.js It uses a different variable to the one I had entered in an if loop

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Sorry bout this but i'm using p5.js for this. I have a variable named pixel line(3) and var size(10) on line 51 in the if statement it uses var size instead of var pixel please help. The majority of the code is irrelevant for this function.

Using the pixel var to be defined by size but no matter what i try it only registers size.

https://editor.p5js.org/Predat0rHeli0J/sketches/zQ6ONgkoW

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] directly in your question? If most of the code is irrelevant, then please narrow your code down to a smaller example that only shows the relevant code.

Comment: Run the sketch and notice that the console.log statements just below where pattern is incremented are never hit. The pattern variable is initialized to 1 but after the first trip through draw it is set to 1 and then is never incremented again. One unrelated thing that I notice is that you are setting framerate to a decimal. Change framerate to a small whole number and it will help you debug.

Comment: It looks like just adding pattern = pattern + 1 right below if (pattern == pattern_set){  //pattern group reset 
  pattern = 1
}
  will allow you to see all your different patterns drawn.